# Google map api looks wrong address

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

When you searched for an address, the map searches for another one that is not, although it is well written

The api google maps have the search function in the box, the problem is when they place the marker is not the correct address

[image: Example Screenshot]

Comment: Sorry, not entirely sure what you're asking. Can you clarify?

Comment: You need to provide some code so we can help you better; and also so that future users who look at your question can get answers.

Comment: The api google maps have the search function in the box, the problem is when they place the marker is not the correct address

Answer (score 1):

The issue for addresses in Bogotá has already been reported in the Google issue tracker and Google team is looking into it. You can see this bug here:

[Incorrect street section/prefix for addresses in Bogotá from Place Autocomplete](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110910555)

Feel free to star the bug to add your vote and subscribe to further notifications from Google.

Currently Google says the following:

> Long story short, Place Autocomplete does not currently support the specific street number format used in these addresses.
>
> "Carrera 18 #84-24 Bogota" refers to the house/building 24 in a section of Carrera 18 where house/building numbers are prefixed with #84, in the part of Carrera 18 immediately North of its intersection with Calle 18:
>   https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#place_id%3DEiFDcmEuIDE4ICM4NC0yNCwgQm9nb3TDoSwgQ29sb21iaWEiGhIYChQKEgnlp5lo9Jo_jhGbtbuxny0NyBAY
>
> The interpretation that Place Autocomplete makes of this address is that of house/building 84 in "a" street called Carrera 18, albeit not on the correct section of Carrera 18.
>
> To workaround this issue, the Geocoding API can be used to find the correct location by geocoding the "description" (not the place_id) of the Autocomplete prediction:
>
> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Cra%2018%20%23%2084-24%20Bogota,%20Colombia
>   description: "Cra. 18 #84-24, Bogotá, Bogota, Colombia",
>   place_id: "EilDcmEuIDE4ICM4NC0yNCwgQm9nb3TDoSwgQm9nb3RhLCBDb2xvbWJpYSIwEi4KFAoSCdctrCjcmD-OEdZ09IVnw0CzEFQqFAoSCR9akpEZmT-OESYqi9UDrswX",
>   types: ["route","geocode"]
>
> [https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Cra.%2018%20%2384-24,%20Bogotá,%20Bogota,%20Colombia](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Cra.%2018%20%2384-24,%20Bogot%C3%A1,%20Bogota,%20Colombia)
>   formatted_address: "Cra. 18 #84-24, Bogotá, Colombia",
>   place_id: "EiFDcmEuIDE4ICM4NC0yNCwgQm9nb3TDoSwgQ29sb21iaWEiGhIYChQKEgnlp5lo9Jo_jhGbtbuxny0NyBAY",
>   types: ["street_address"]

Comment: good afternoon, thank you very much for the solution but I do not know what to do to my code to search me correctly, my code is similar to this example of google documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/ examples / places-searchbox? hl = en, I do not know what to implement to solve it.